# Can you make an App overlay with Flutter on Android/iOS?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, mobile

I am curious if it is possible to make an overlay with flutter which shows above the current app (android / iOS).
I imagine it like the google translate app (as I do not have enough reputation I can only post a link to an image):

[Google Translator example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GHLqH.png)